# This project type is not supported by Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, windows-phone

I'm following the book "Creating mobile apps with Xamarin.Forms". I have full trial account on Xamarin but the samples only builds Android projects and shows the error in title for winapp and winphone, I've updated and restored the nuget packages.

Comment: please open this file `.csproj` and copy in your question the `ProjectTypeGuids` please. It's like `E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401 `

Comment: for winapp: {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3},;{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC} , for winphone {C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}, for winphone8.1 {76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

Comment: So the problem is that you can not create an Android project?

Comment: i can only create android projects no windows phone

Comment: Make sure you have installed :[`Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (C#)`](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/)

Comment: If you are not able installing this, I recomend you to uninstall all the `Xamarin` even the files that are on your `%APPDATA%` and then reinstall it again.

Comment: Have you uninstalled it and reinstall?

Comment: yep, are their any alternatives to xamarin, can be any language as long as i can use the same codebase for all three plattform?

Comment: Xamarin Studio does not support Windows Phone and Store apps. You will have to install Visual Studio such as Commmunity Edition along. The book makes this clear in the very beginning but it seems that you skipped the relevant chapters.

Comment: okej, but what about IOS? ive setup a server with xcode, for windows phone then it means i have to get buissniess license?

Comment: @LexLi FIY I have a Visual Studio Community Edition and it still does not support Windows Project